# How to configure the color on Git Commit Message when using vscode as difftool?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm wondering how could I setup the color on the vscode Git Commit Message window on my M1 MacBook.

I recently bought this laptop and using vscode as my default difftool shows me no color. All my configuration works perfectly (as in git config, etc., nothing that disrupts the color itself) and the color shows when using the `git diff` command. So it's just the part of vscode and it's language settings.

I've been looking for a solution for a while in multiple sites, threads, issues etc., but couldn't find anything.

If someone has any idea, I'm all ears.

Thank you

Comment: you want to give the commit message textbox a color?

Comment: Indeed. With other OS distributions I'm able to see the lines added, lines removed, in green and red like a typical git diff would work. But in this laptop when using VSCode as my difftool, when I "git commit", I see the git commit message in plain white.

Comment: that is not the `git commit` message, the `git commit` message is a piece of text describing what the commit does and you see that in the `git log`, you enter it in a textbox or on the command line with `git commit -m`

Comment: Maybe I did not explain correctly. Using vscode as the core editor of git, in the moment you ```git commit``` it will open vscode to enter the message. This is recognised as it's "own language" in vscode called ```Git Commit message```. Here you can enter the commit message/description, and you see appended the ```git diff``` of the commit. This appended ```git diff``` has no color on my M1, when other OS have the color. ```git diff``` has the correct color also when using it on my terminal (iterm2).

Comment: using `git diff` in the terminal is completely different from VSC diff. If it is really the `git diff` from the terminal (with +++ and ---, >>>, <<<) than it has stripped the ANSI color codes